# RxJS, Angular: Cannot receive result of subscription in other methods

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a Angular Component like this:

It creates a normal ReplaySubject. (see `constructor`).
Then some other component get the `subject` via the method `getSubject()` and subscribes to it. Another Component sets a new value via `setValue`. This value should be received by the Subscribers. However, this does not happen. It receives nothing, even no error.

```
@Injectable()
export class BreadcrumbService {

    subject: ReplaySubject<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.subject = new ReplaySubject<string>();
        console.log('Step 1: Subject created');
    }

    getSubject(): ReplaySubject<string> {
        console.log('Step 2: Return subject for subscribing');
        return this.subject;
    }

    setValue(title: string) {
        console.log('Step 3: Invoke a new value which should be received in the Subscriber of step 2.');
        this.subject.next(title);
    }
}
```

If I place the subscription inside `setValue()` it works as expected.

Here is my Component which should receive the subscription:

```
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private breadcrumbsService: BreadcrumbService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.breadcrumbsService.getSubject()
            .subscribe(
                success => {
                    console.log(success); // is never called
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error); // is never called
                }
            );
    }
}
```

How can my subscriber receive this value?

Comment: have you checked with what @Gunter has said? other than everything should work without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen a mistake but
I assume you provide `BreadcrumbService` more than once.
Angular2 maintains a single instance per provider. If you provide more than once there will be multiple instances. I assume that the instance that calls `setValue` does it on a different instance than the `BreadcrumbComponent` got.

If you want a shared instance provide it at a common parent (for example the root componeent).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! You are absolutely right. I provided the `BreadcrumbService` two times.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Observables` instead.

```
@Injectable()
export class BreadcrumbService {

   subject: Observables<string>;

   constructor() {
       this.subject = new Observables<string>();
       console.log('Step 1: Subject created');
   }

   getSubject(): Observables<string> {
       console.log('Step 2: Return subject for subscribing');
       return this.subject;
   }

   setValue(title: string) {
       console.log('Step 3: Invoke a new value which should be received in the Subscriber of step 2.');
       this.subject.emit(title);
   }
}
```